# Button Counter-Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, counter, actionlistener

I need help making a program that has 2 button. A message appears “I was clicked n time!” whenever the button is clicked. Each button should have a separate click count.

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class ButtonViewer
    {
      private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
      private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 360;


 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     int counter1 = 0;
     int counter2 = 0;

     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
     frame.add(button);

     JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
     JButton button2 = new JButton("Click me too!");
     frame2.add(button2);

     ActionListener listener = new ClickListener();
     button.addActionListener(listener);
     button2.addActionListener(listener);

     counter1++;
     counter2++;

     frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setVisible(true);

     frame2.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
     frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame2.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: We won't do your homework for you, but we'll help you with it. Try stuff out, tell us where you're stuck. And if you've put clear effort it, we'll push you in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried something to solve the problem?

Comment: Your code example is not complete. `ClickListener` is missing. You haven't understood the basics of event handling in Swing. Have a look at [the Java tutorial section covering simple event handling in swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html).

Comment: That's why i'm stuck lol I dont know what else to do. My professor is not good so i've been trying to teach myself how to do this. Any suggestions in english what I should do? I dont know how to assign a button a counter, or have a window come from a window that's already there.

Answer (score 3):

To start your going to need to actually add a ClickListener, by actually writing another method below like:

```
private class listener1 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        counter1++;
    }
}
```

you have 2 of these classes in this case... one per button.
The second listener would just increment the other counter, when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to implement the ActionListener inline. Just do:

```
button2.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
...
});
```

When implementing the actionperfomed method in there, you can easily change the text of button2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a call back for the action listener, therefore when you click on the button, the listen knows something is happening but don't have any instruction on what to do. Like @KingWilliam mention, this looks like homework, so looking into action listener call back should be enough to get your gears moving.

Answer (score 0):

the listener is an interface, so in the implementation class, you need to make sure that the actionPerformed() method is implemented. you just need to detect the resource of the 'click' event, if it is coming from button increase the button's counter, and to the same to the button2,.

Answer (score 0):

intialize two variables for the count, say count1,count2. For Button 1 register anonymous class as an event listener like this:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        count1++;
        new CustomMessage(count1);
    }
});
```

where CustomMessage should be like:

```
class CustomMessage extends javax.swing.JDialog{
    public CustomMessage( int counter){
    //...
    }
}
```

make sure to incorporate 'counter' in your message.
Follow similarly for button2. Hope this works for you! 
Best of Luck.